# apply display none to a class where another class is available in the same DOM in JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have HTML codes (present in the same DOM) in which I want to apply a logic that if a particular class is available on DOM, then style display none 
should be applied to a different class which is present in the same DOM.

**HTML Code#1**

```
<div class="cpac-video__inner">
   <div class="vjs-playing vjs-has-started" >   // If vjs-playing vjs-has-started classes are present in a DOM 

   </div>  
</div>
```

**HTML Code#2**

```
<span class="video-hl video-cat HW">   // then style display none should be applied to HW class
    <span class="cpac-icon cpac-icon-hl-link-flip tv-logo"></span>ABC  
</span>
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-playing vjs-has-started");

if(elementExists)
{
document.getElementsByClassName("HW").style.display = "none";
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to do in the script above so that when paricular class is available in a DOM then 
style display none should be applied to a different class in the same DOM.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("HW") returns a node list. You should iterator through it to have each of the list items get "display: none".

Comment: Where does the **HTML Code #2** resides? Is it a descendant of **HTML Code #1**?

Comment: Note: that getElementsByClassName need index.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Both `HTML Code#1` and `HTML Code#2` are in the same DOM.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("HW")[0].style.display = "none";`

Comment: Yes, but where are they in relation to each other? Is the `span` a child of the `div`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir No spam is not a child of div. They are both are at same level but none of them are parent/child of each other.

Comment: @Mukyuu Can you explain me in the answer? comments are confusing me.

Comment: @Mukyuu I tried your code but it didn't work. When class `vjs-playing vjs-has-started` is present in the DOM then style display none should be applied to class HW.

Answer (score 0):

See what you have before:

```js
var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-playing vjs-has-started");

if(elementExists)
{
document.getElementsByClassName("HW").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="cpac-video__inner">
   <div class="vjs-playing vjs-has-started" >   // If vjs-playing vjs-has-started classes are present in a DOM 

   </div>  
</div>


<span class="video-hl video-cat HW">   // then style display none should be applied to HW class
    <span class="cpac-icon cpac-icon-hl-link-flip tv-logo"></span>ABC
```

it return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined` which is resulted by `getElementsByClassName` returning not a direct value but array of all class which contain that name.

See the following:

```js
var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-playing vjs-has-started")[0];
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-playing vjs-has-started"));

if(elementExists)
{
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("HW"));
document.getElementsByClassName("HW")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="cpac-video__inner">
   <div class="vjs-playing vjs-has-started" >   // If vjs-playing vjs-has-started classes are present in a DOM 

   </div>  
</div>


<span class="video-hl video-cat HW">   // then style display none should be applied to HW class
    <span class="cpac-icon cpac-icon-hl-link-flip tv-logo"></span>ABC
```

Notice the difference between adding `[0]` which point to first index and without. That's because [`getElementByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.